# JSONNODE was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, libjson

I have just installed libjson from sourceforge.net . I tried executing a simple program But i get this error

```
‘JSONNode’ was not declared in this scope
```

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>

#include <libjson.h>

int main()
{
    JSONNode n(JSON_NODE);
    JSONNode c(JSON_ARRAY);
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 16));
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 43));
    c.push_back(JSONNode("", 69));

    n.push_back(c);

    std::string jc = n.write_formatted();
    std::cout<<jc<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

M I missing some header file ?

Comment: Did you make sure `libjson.h` was saved in the same project folder as this `.cpp` file?

Comment: Is it in some namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that libjson stuff is defined in the `json` namespace. Please try adding `json::` in front of `JSONNode` solve the problem? Like this:

```
json::JSONNode n(JSON_NODE);
json::JSONNode c(JSON_ARRAY);
```

Comment: didnt solve the problem . I get 'json has not been declared' error.

Comment: On which line is the error? Did you place `json::` in front of the other too?

Comment: I tired replacing as you pointed out . It complains that 'json' has not been declared.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable `#define JSON_LIBRARY` in `JSONOptions.h`, otherwise libjson won't include the C++ headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to build the libJson library first.

I followed the following thread and it worked great for me after having the same problem you are having:

For running the Make File:
`http://stackoverflow.com/a/11865407/1399434e`

Answer (score 0):

disable the JSON_LIBRARY in JSONOptions.h

```
//#define JSON_LIBRARY
```

then compile again as below

```
#include "libjson.h"
using namespace libjson;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    JSONNode* pNode = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```